How to get the shape of a schema in zod when using superRefine?
For a simple zod schema like this
const schema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string(),
    age: z.number()
  })

I have this code which works fine :
export const handleForm =
  (schema: z.AnyZodObject) =>
  (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    const keys = Object.keys(schema.shape) as unknown as Array<keyof z.infer<typeof schema>>;

    const arrayKeys = keys.filter(key => schema.shape[key] instanceof z.ZodArray);

    const values = Object.fromEntries(
      Array.from(data.keys()).map(key => [key, arrayKeys.includes(key) ? data.getAll(key) : data.get(key)]),
    );

The cool of this, is that we can introspect the zod schema, to know if a key of the object is an array, and if so, to use FormData.getAll instead of get.
Now, I have some edge cases which need to use superRefine :
const schema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string(),
    age: z.number()
  })
.superRefine( ...)

This time, the schema is not inferred as z.AnyZodObject but a z.ZodEffects<z.AnyZodObject>.
Unfortunately, this type has no shape property to be introspected.
I have see somme internal API (_input, _output, _def) but I can't figure out how to use them.
I don't really understand either why a superRefine changes the type. OK if we use transform, coerce but I believed that superRefine was just a mean to throw an error and didn't change the type ?

Using the method: innerType() or sourceType(): ej: z.object({}).superRefine(()=>{}).sourceType()
